# What is the fastest way to get lists of files and search through file lists repeatedly?

Tags: c#, dictionary

What is the fastest way to get lists of files and search through file lists repeatedly?

Situation:

1. There can be 5,000 to 35,000 files spread over 3-5 root directories (that have many subdirectories) on a network drive.
2. There are three file types (tif, sus, img) that a user may or may not search for.  Some file types can have 2-3 different file extensions.
3. From a list of files (in various database tables), I need to find out if each file exists, and if it does, save the path only and filename only to a table.
4. Searches on file names must be case sensitive but it would be nice to keep original case when saving the path to the table.

Environment:

C# and .NET 4.0 on Windows PC.

Is this the fastest way?:

Is the fastest way to use a dictionary, with FileName as a key (lowercase) and Path as a value (original case)?
In this way I can get the index/Path at the same pass when I search for the filename?  The FileName and Path are split up front when populating the list.

```
if (d.TryGetValue("key", out value))
{
    // Log "key" and value to table  // only does one lookup
}
```

Note: I am a bit concerned that I probably will have duplicate key values per FileType.
When/If I run across this scenario what type of list and access method should I use?

Maybe on these rare cases, I should populate another list of the duplicate keys.  Because I will need to do at least one of: log/copy/delete of the files in any path.

Comment: I would probably create an object with "FullFilePath" and "FileName"/"Path" getters that extract those details from the path. Then, create a collection of those objects that you can iterate over. --but that's just me.

Comment: @BradChristie So... the [`FileInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) class, then?

Comment: @SpikeX: I thought about it, but FileInfo may be to heavy just for meta-data. It depends what you want to performance. I almost think a dumb struct set up in an [easily-searchable collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009107/what-net-collection-provides-the-fastest-search)

Comment: @BradChristie But that's all a FileInfo object is, is metadata. It doesn't store the contents of the file at all. They're designed to be very lightweight and quick, and I've processed *hundreds of thousands* of files with the FileInfo class and had no problems whatsoever. -- **Don't reinvent the wheel.** ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a `Dictionary<string,string>` with the FullName (path+file+ext) changed to lower case as key and the FullName unchanged as value. Then split the required parts using the static methods `GetDirectoryName` and `GetFileName` of the `System.IO.Path` class before inserting them into the table.

**EDIT**: The `GetFiles` method of the `DirectoryInfo` class returns an array of `FileInfo`. `FileInfo` has a `FullName` property returning path+file+ext. You could as well store this `FileInfo` as value in your dictionary if memory consumption is not an issue. `FileInfo` has a `DirectoryName` and a `Name` property returning the two parts you need.

**EDIT**: Here is my implementation of a multimap which does the `Directory<TKey,List<TValue>>` stuff:

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents a collection of keys and values. Multiple values can have the same key.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TKey">Type of the keys.</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="TValue">Type of the values.</typeparam>
public class MultiMap<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, List<TValue>>
{

    public MultiMap()
        : base()
    {
    }

    public MultiMap(int capacity)
        : base(capacity)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds an element with the specified key and value into the MultiMap. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key">The key of the element to add.</param>
    /// <param name="value">The value of the element to add.</param>
    public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        List<TValue> valueList;

        if (TryGetValue(key, out valueList)) {
            valueList.Add(value);
        } else {
            valueList = new List<TValue>();
            valueList.Add(value);
            Add(key, valueList);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Removes first occurence of a element with a specified key and value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key">The key of the element to remove.</param>
    /// <param name="value">The value of the element to remove.</param>
    /// <returns>true if the a element is removed; false if the key or the value were not found.</returns>
    public bool Remove(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        List<TValue> valueList;

        if (TryGetValue(key, out valueList)) {
            if (valueList.Remove(value)) {
                if (valueList.Count == 0) {
                    Remove(key);
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Removes all occurences of elements with a specified key and value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key">The key of the elements to remove.</param>
    /// <param name="value">The value of the elements to remove.</param>
    /// <returns>Number of elements removed.</returns>
    public int RemoveAll(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        List<TValue> valueList;
        int n = 0;

        if (TryGetValue(key, out valueList)) {
            while (valueList.Remove(value)) {
                n++;
            }
            if (valueList.Count == 0) {
                Remove(key);
            }
        }
        return n;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the total number of values contained in the MultiMap.
    /// </summary>
    public int CountAll
    {
        get
        {
            int n = 0;

            foreach (List<TValue> valueList in Values) {
                n += valueList.Count;
            }
            return n;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether the MultiMap contains a element with a specific key / value pair.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key">Key of the element to search for.</param>
    /// <param name="value">Value of the element to search for.</param>
    /// <returns>true if the element was found; otherwise false.</returns>
    public bool Contains(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        List<TValue> valueList;

        if (TryGetValue(key, out valueList)) {
            return valueList.Contains(value);
        }
        return false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether the MultiMap contains a element with a specific value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">Value of the element to search for.</param>
    /// <returns>true if the element was found; otherwise false.</returns>
    public bool Contains(TValue value)
    {
        foreach (List<TValue> valueList in Values) {
            if (valueList.Contains(value)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: When I am searching for a file I only have the file name from the database table.  so shouldn't the key just be the file name?  Since performance really matters I would rather match on the whole string.  right?

Comment: So you know only the filename, but don't know in which directory it is? Then you could use a `Directory<string,List<string>>` or a `Directory<string,List<FileInfo>>` to store multiple file informations for the same file name.

Comment: I am guessing (don't know for sure) but since duplicates will be rare I think having 2 lists is faster per FileType.  Normal list = Dictonary<filename, PathOnly, and the duplicate list = Dictionary<filename, List<PathOnly>>.  But for every positive match I will have to check the other list. hmmm

Comment: Having 2 dicts is complicated and will probably not be significantly faster (if at all). Use my implementation of `MultiMap` it's easy and will be fast enough (see my EDIT). Note that `TryGetValue` returns a `List<TValue>` not a `TValue`.

Comment: Thanks! Will try this today/tomorrow and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use a dictionary with filename lowercased as key.  Value would be a class with the needed extra information.  I would also search it like your example.  If this was slow I would probably also try searching with linq just to see if it was faster.  This is however one problem here; this requires that all files through all folders are uniquely named.  That might be the case for you, but it could also be a problem if you haven't already considered it ;)

Remember that you can also use a FileWatcher object to keep the memory dictionary/list synchronized with the disk contents if it is subject to change.  If it's static I would probably store it all in a database table and search that instead, startup of your program would then be instatanious.

Edit:
Just now noticed your conscern for duplicates.  If that's a problem I would create a List where fileclass is a class containing needed information on the files.  Then search the list using linq as that could give you zero, one or more hits.  I think that would be more efficient than a dictionary with a list as value, where the list would contain one or more items (duplicates).

Comment: How do you feel about adding the overhead of LINQ with regards to speed? (just curious)

Comment: The files are indeed static - FileWatcher will not be needed.

Comment: I have considered duplicate keys and think the fastest solution may be another dictionary for duplicates List<fullpath, pathonly>.  My database I am using is MS Access 2007 so I think a dictionary list is much faster than searching this Db table.   Do I really need a class? I just need to store FileName, Path.  Do you think the List<FileClass> idea would be faster than 2 dictionaries for my simple purposes?