# Using Dictionary<Foo, Foo> Instead of List<Foo> to Speed up Calls to Contains()

Tags: c#, list, collections, dictionary

I have a question about generic collections in C#. If I need to store a collection of items, and I'm frequently going to need to check whether an item is in the collection, would it be faster to use Dictionary instead of List?

I've heard that checking if an item is in the collection is linear relative to the size for lists and constant relative to the size for dictionaries. Is using Dictionary and then setting Key and Value to the same object for each key-value pair something that other programmers frequently do in this situation?

Thanks for taking the time to read this.

Comment: How many items in the list?  If you have 100, this would be pre-optimization, and it doesn't matter.

Comment: You're using `Dioctionary<Foo,Foo>` like a `HashSet<Foo>`, which should technically be faster, but you should compare them using `Stopwatch` either way.

Comment: Duplicate. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009107/what-net-collection-provides-the-fastest-search.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, yes it is.  That said, you probably want to use `HashSet` because you don't need both a key and a value, you just need a set of items.

It's also worth noting that `Dictionary` was added in C# 2.0, and `HashSet` was added in 3.5, so for all that time inbetween it was actually fairly common to use a Dictionary when you wanted a Set just because that was all you had (without rolling your own).  When I was forced to do this I just stuck null in the value, rather than the item as the key and value, but the idea is the same.

Comment: Thanks guys! This is just what I needed to know. I was pretty sure that there was a cleaner, neater way of doing this than using Dictionary<Foo, Foo>.

Answer (score 5):

Just use `HashSet<Foo>` if what you're concerned with is fast containment tests.

A `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is for looking a value up based on a key.

A `List<T>` is for random access and dynamic growth properties.

A `HashSet<T>` is for modeling a set and providing fast containment tests.

You're not looking up a value based on a key. You're not worried about random access, but rather fast containment checks. The right concept here is a `HashSet<T>`.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that there is only ever one copy of the item in the list, then the appropriate data structure is `ISet<T>`, specifically `HashSet<T>`.

That said, I've seen timing that indicate that a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` `ContainsKey` call is a wee bit faster than even `HashSet<T>`.  Either way, both of them are going to be loads faster than a plain `List<T>` lookup.

Keep in mind that both of these methods (HashSet and Dictionary) rely on reasonably well-implemented `Equals` ***and*** `GetHashcode` implementations for `T`.  `List<T>` only relies on `Equals`

Answer (score 3):

A Dictionary, or HashSet will use more memory, but provide (almost) O(1) seek time.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at [HashSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx), which is a collection of unique objects (as long as the object implements IEquality comparer).

Answer (score 1):

You mention using `List<T>`, which implies that ordering may be important. If this is the case then you may also want to look into the `SortedSet<T>` type as well.